# Disquisitiones Arithmeticae Chapter 8?

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know where I can find the posthumously published (I think) chapter 8 of Gauss's Disquisitiones Arithmaticae?

Comment: Dunno, but both of [this](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3356j) and [this](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k994003.r) have only seven parts. Same for [this](http://www.e-rara.ch/doi/10.3931/e-rara-4025) other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [German edition](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disquisitiones_Arithmeticae) of Wikipedia you can find the eighth chapter in [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN23599524X&IDDOC=137221).

Answer (score 1):

Go to archive.org and look up Gauss' Werke, Band 1.  This is in German and it includes the unfinished notes that would have become part of Section 8.  But I would strongly recommend reading Mathews book on number theory first because it attempts to go over the content of Gauss' DA in a more up-to-date and accessible fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I have read some information that it may have been published as 'General Investigations of Curved Surfaces' however I am having some difficulty confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Maser's 1889 German translation has on the title page: "the last third of the text contains Gauss's published papers on The Theory of Numbers, followed by his posthumous writings on that subject". It's about 230 pp., tacked onto books I-VII of Disquisitiones. It's available as a reprint (mine is Chelsea press). I don't know if this is considered to be the missing book or not ... is there consensus about what the proper content of book VIII would have been?